# How to stream MP3 files through IIS smooth streaming technique

Tags: encoding, mp3, smooth-streaming

In my project I have requirement to stream MP3 files from IIS using Smooth streaming technique. I believe we can achieve the same by encoding MP3 files to .isma files (audio only streaming). My question is how to encode these MP3 files using Expression Encoder SDK (not through Expression Encoder GUI tool) or is there any different technique to stream MP3 through IIS without using smooth streaming ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem by using MediaElement control and with Progressive download technique.  Just specify the Source Property of MediaElement control with the Url of MP3 file.